# What is alternative of php's $_SERVER in nodejs

Tags: php, node.js

I have a php script where I am using `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];` right at start of script. I then need to check what is request being sent like 'GET', 'POST' etc. Sharing some of the php script as below.

```
<?php
try {
  $method_name = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]) {
   // more code
  }
}
?>
```

What I trying currently is creating a new server with node as follow.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 console.log(req.method).
 if(req.method === 'POST') {
   // more code
 }
}).listen(8080);
```

Currently it is not working as my php script, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Your node.js code has a syntax error, but you are checking correctly the method. You just have to end the request when you're done via `res.end` so that the browser knows it got the full response.

```js
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    console.log('Received "' + req.method + '" request!');

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        res.end('This was a POST request');
        return;
    }

    res.end('This was a GET request');
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: Okay, Can you also help me find alternatives for $_POST['secret']; $_POST['type'];  and 
     $resp->message = "Success";

Comment: Also, can you let me know, how can I pass request method while running this node script from terminal?

Comment: @UmairJameel to process POST data it's harder to implement in NodeJS. I would suggest to find a tutorial and find it. Generally I would also recommend using a framework like Express for this. There are also responses on SO on how to process POST data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-to-process-post-data-in-node-js

Comment: @UmairJameel also for making POST requests from terminal you could use `curl -X POST -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:8080/`